# How to transfer unicode string to another format in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to query data like `"Morristown\\u002c_New_Jersey"`. Because in my database, `"Morristown\\u002c_New_Jersey"` is like `"Morristown\$002C_New_Jersey"`. The `"\\u"` become `"\$"` and the lowercase in unicode become uppercase. Is there a neat way to process all the kinds of data?

Comment: simply use `String.replaceAll("\\$","\\u");`

Comment: This looks like you should fix the code to insert data into database, rather than fixing the corrupted text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Java code with regex `\\\\u([^_]+)` to replace Unicode character code with DB equivalence:

```
String str = "Jos\\u00e9_A\\u002e_Santos";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([^_]+)").matcher(str);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "\\\\\\$" + matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println("The original string "+ str+ "\n has been converted "+ sb.toString());
```

prints:

```
The original string Jos\u00e9_A\u002e_Santos
 has been converted Jos\$00E9_A\$002E_Santos
```

The code is along the [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) class documentation.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/cDZwvW) and [regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/zF6sC9/2)

Comment: Hi I used your solution but it has a bug. When facing the case like "Jos\\u00e9_A\\u002e_Santos" it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Updated for multiple matches